# Как работает XPath в данном случае? или как улучшить метод?

Tags: java, selenium, test-automation

Есть метод который помещает в некоторое поле (destinyLocator) случайное число генерируемое на основе некоторых значений на странице (minLocator, maxLocator)
Для поиска элементов используется xpath

```
void setRandomValue(WebDriver driver, String minLocator, String maxLocator, String destinyLocator) {
    //Находим минимальное число
    this.minValueString = driver.findElement(By.xpath(minLocator)).getText();
    //Находим максимальное число
    this.maxValueString = driver.findElement(By.xpath(maxLocator)).getText();
    //setMinMax генерирует случайное число на основе minValue и maxValue 
    this.setMinMax();
```

Дальше мы берем со страницы заранее приготовленный массив инпутов, из него достаем тот, на который осуществили клик ранее в программе и заполняем его получившимся из setMinMax числом

```
this.getInputsArray().get(this.randomElem).findElement(By.xpath(destinyLocator)).sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE, Integer.toString(this.randomInputValue));
    this.writeLog(">Введенное значение: " + this.randomInputValue);
}
```

Проблема же вот в чем

При вводе вот такого destinyLocator заполняется всегда только ПЕРВЫЙ инпут найденный в массиве независимо от того, через какой элемент я инициирую findElement

`"//div[@class='common-form-element__input-item']//input");`

Comment: ./div[@class='common-form-element__input-item']/input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.//div[@class='common-form-element__input-item']//input[@type='number']`

Помогло обращение через .//